# Why are there so many XFS processes？

Tags: linux, xfs

My centos7 system has seen many of the following XFS processes viewed using ***ps aux | wc-l*** to see about 500 processes， But I don't understand why there are so many XFS processes？

Here's some of them

```
root     31668  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:30   0:00 [kworker/2:2H]
root     31875  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   18:51   0:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root     32434  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [kdmflush]
root     32435  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [bioset]
root     32438  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-buf/dm-38]
root     32439  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-data/dm-38]
root     32440  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-conv/dm-38]
root     32441  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-cil/dm-38]
root     32442  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-reclaim/dm-]
root     32443  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-log/dm-38]
root     32444  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   12:51   0:00 [xfs-eofblocks/d]
root     32445  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    12:51   0:00 [xfsaild/dm-38]
```

The is the result of "dmesg | grep XFS"

```
[385702.793982] XFS (dm-34): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[385702.821640] XFS (dm-34): Ending clean mount
[385702.846183] XFS (dm-34): Unmounting Filesystem
[385702.917698] XFS (dm-34): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[385702.934293] XFS (dm-34): Ending clean mount
[385702.937572] XFS (dm-34): Unmounting Filesystem
[385703.012295] XFS (dm-34): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[385703.024738] XFS (dm-34): Ending clean mount
[385708.134097] XFS (dm-64): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[385708.175139] XFS (dm-64): Ending clean mount
[385711.080569] XFS (dm-64): Unmounting Filesystem
[385711.196898] XFS (dm-64): Mounting V4 Filesystem
[385711.220774] XFS (dm-64): Ending clean mount
[385717.117652] XFS (dm-64): Unmounting Filesystem
```

I'm Google but didn't find a good explanation but I don't a good explain。

Comment: [SE] is not a forum; it is a question and answer site.  Our rules are a bit stricter than forums’.  While I see, generally, what your question is *about,* I don’t see an actual question (i.e., a sentence ending with a ‘?’). Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your post to make your question clearer and more complete.

Comment: the real question is why your filesystem is mounted twice a second.

Answer (score -1):

This happens when a disk is detached from the system while it is still mounted.

Edit to add: I do this to myself most often when I am using a lower privilege identity, cd /mnt/somedisk, then sudo -i to accomplish something, but don't exit before trying to dismount. The dismount will fail due to the lower privilege user still sitting on the mount in the background.